# How to strip a comma in the middle of a large number?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert a str number into a float or int numerical type. However, it is throwing an error that it can't, so I am removing the comma. The comma will not be removed, so I need to find a way of finding a way of designating the location in the number space like say fourth.

```
power4 = power[power.get('Number of Customers Affected') != 'Unknown']
power5 = power4[pd.notnull(power4['Number of Customers Affected'])]
power6 = power5[power5.get('NERC Region') == 'RFC']
power7 = power6.get('Number of Customers Affected').loc[1]
power8 = power7.strip(",")
power9 = float(power8)


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-70- 32ca4deb9734> in <module>
      6 power7 = power6.get('Number of Customers Affected').loc[1]
      7 power8 = power7.strip(",")
----> 8 power9 = float(power8)
      9 
     10 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '127,000'
```

Comment: See the documentation: ".strip" does *not* remove characters from the middle of a string, but only from the ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use replace()

```
float('127,000'.replace(',',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [pandas.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)?

```
import pandas as pd

a = '1234'
type(a)

a = pd.to_numeric(a)
type(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the

```
power8 = power7.strip(",")
```

line, do

```
power8 = power7.replace(',', '')
```

strip() will not work here. What is required is replace() method of string. You may also try

```
''.join(e for e in s if e.isdigit())
```

Or,

```
s = ''.join(s.split(','))
```

RegeEx can also be a way to solve this, or you can have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/266162/9851541